# Add second processor to Virtualbox virtualized 32bit Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu 32bit virtualized machine for some time now on my 4 processor server. I gave it one processor but now I need more power. I added the second in Virtualbox settings but virtualized ubuntu still thinks it's only one processor:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6600  @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 11
cpu MHz     : 2405.790
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5 
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc up pni ssse3 lahf_lm
bogomips    : 4811.58
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Is there a way to make my virtualized Ubuntu machine aware of a second processor?

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in Virtualbox documentation on [CPU Hot-Plugging](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#cpuhotplug). That details the procedure of adding another CPU to Linux guests.

> With Linux guests, the following applies: To prevent ejection while
>   the CPU is still used it has to be ejected from within the guest
>   before. The Linux Guest Additions contain a service which receives
>   hot-remove events and ejects the CPU. Also, after a CPU is added to
>   the VM it is not automatically used by Linux. The Linux Guest
>   Additions service will take care of that if installed. If not a CPU
>   can be started with the following command:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<id>/online
```

On the [Known Limitations](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html) page, some drawbacks of the SMP capabilities of 32bit guests are listed. Mostly performance issues:

> Poor performance with 32-bit guests on certain Intel CPU models that
>   do not include virtual APIC hardware optimization support. This
>   affects mainly Windows and Solaris guests, but possibly also some
>   Linux kernel revisions. Partially solved in 3.0.12 for 32 bits Windows
>   NT, 2000, XP and 2003 guests. Requires 3.0.12 or higher Guest
>   Additions to be installed.

It does not say that multi processing is not possible.

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't work. I have Virtualbox additions installed and this trick with echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuid... there is no such directory on my virtual ubuntu.

Comment: Make sure you replace `<id>` with a number eg. `0, 1`, etc. So that the file name gets `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online`. Also please read the Hot-Plugging chapter, because the VM needs some preparation to be able to handle the hot plugging.

Comment: of course :) But it's simply not there, online file/directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have hands-on experience, so I'm just guessing. If you have the `cpu1` directory (and you should, since you added a new CPU), you could try to create the `online` file with the above command and see if the CPU gets used. Or as an alternative, the VBoxManage commands could help.

Comment: /sys/devices/system/cpu there is a online offline file here, not in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0, I'll try modifying that file today, after all users have disconnected from my virtual machine and will state results.